# Cannot figure out problem with random.randint(x,y)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program where you think of a number and the computer tries to guess it by going higher and lower but it refuses to work. I've narrowed the problem down to line 6 or 7 by trimming bits of the program in and out but I have no idea what's wrong with those lines in order to fix it.

```
import random
print("Think of a number between 0 - 100\nType:\n'Higher' if the number is too low\n'Lower' if the number is too high\n'Correct' if the number is correct")
minRange = 0
maxRange = 100
while True: 
    comGuess = random.randint(minRange,maxRange)
    print("Is it " + comGuess + "?")   
    answer = input("")
    if answer == "Higher" or answer == "higher" or answer == "h":
        minRange = comGuess
    elif answer == "Lower" or answer == "lower" or answer == "l":
        maxRange = comGuess
    elif answer == "Correct" or answer == "correct" or answer == "c":
        input("Yay I won!")
        break
    else:
        print("I don't understand")
```

As far as I can tell it should say a number, you provide a response and it guesses again and again with ever narrowing parameters until it gets the correct answer. I'm still learning Python but the lack of error message is really stumping me, the program just opens and instantly closes. I have the input on the correct answer so the program doesn't instantly close upon a correct answer

Comment: The error is in the print statement, you're concatenating an int to a string, you must wrap the integer in str() like `str(comGuess)`, python should be giving a pretty clear error when running that.

Comment: How are you running it? If you're running it by something like double-clicking on it then it will print the error and exit so quickly you won't be able to see the error. Trying running it in a terminal window with something like `python guess.py` or whatever is appropriate for your system.

Comment: I'm still learning how to use stack overflow so I don't know how to directly reply but thankyou for the solution. I'm using Notepad++ to run it as a program as it's much easier than directly in the python application

Comment: Notepad++ easier than IDLE?

Comment: I don't know what IDLE is

Comment: _but it refuses to work_ We have no idea what this means.  What, exactly, do you mean "does not work"?  If you're getting an error message, show us.  If you're getting unexpected results, show us, and explain what you expected instead.

Comment: I go on to explain what I intend for it to do and what it does instead, you gotta read past the first sentence

Comment: I would like to re-emphasize what @President said: it is very, very unusual for a Python program to exit with no error message, but you will always need to run the script an environment where the message will stay visible long enough to read it.  The command line is one good way.  Debugging Python is a hundred times easier when you know exactly what line is crashing, and why.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention how you run this program. If you just double click on the .py file, it may run, have an error and exit before you see it. Running from the command line would help in that case. You could also wrap the whole thing in a `try:` then a `finally:` block that does `input("Press any key to terminate")` to give you a better chance of seeing the error.

Comment: I find it difficult to do it in a command line because I always slip in typo's and in order to fix them I have to type out the entire thing again. I find notepadd++ more convenient because I can edit previously written lines without rewritting the entire prgoram

Comment: notepad++ is a good tool. I've used it in Windows many times. By "command line" I mean the Windows command line. It sounds like you've been calling python and getting its shell (A.K.A. REPL - read-eval-print loop) with the `>>> ` prompt. It would be common to edit in notepad++ but also have a command window open on the same directory to run your program for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on line 7, change `print("Is it " + comGuess + "?")` to `print("Is it " + str(comGuess) + "?")`. This works because you're trying to combine a string and an int (a number) in a print function, and that won't work, so you have to convert the int to a str first

Comment: You could have also used commas instead of plus, `print` knows how to print multiple things.

Comment: Another way to do it is:
`print(f"Is it {comGuess}?)`